# Convert decimal int to little endian string ('\x##\x##...')

Tags: python

I want to convert an integer value to a string of hex values, in little endian.  For example, `5707435436569584000` would become `'\x4a\xe2\x34\x4f\x4a\xe2\x34\x4f'`.

All my googlefu is finding for me is `hex(..)` which gives me `'0x4f34e24a4f34e180'` which is not what I want.

I could probably manually split up that string and build the one I want but I'm hoping somone can point me to a better option.

Comment: Your example is for `5707435436569584202`, not `5707435436569584000`.

Comment: You're right.  Scrolling back through my interpreter's history I see where i started using the wrong number but no idea why it happened.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<Q', 5707435436569584000)
'\x80\xe14OJ\xe24O'
>>> struct.pack('<Q', 5707435436569584202)
'J\xe24OJ\xe24O'
```

Here `<` indicates little-endian, and `Q` that we want to pack a unsigned long long (8 bytes).

Note that Python will use ASCII characters for any byte that falls within the printable ASCII range to represent the resulting bytestring, hence the `14OJ`, `24O` and `J` parts of the above result:

```
>>> struct.pack('<Q', 5707435436569584202).encode('hex')
'4ae2344f4ae2344f'
>>> '\x4a\xe2\x34\x4f\x4a\xe2\x34\x4f'
'J\xe24OJ\xe24O'
```

Comment: And to finish the job: `'\\x' + '\\x'.join(x.encode('hex') for x in struct.pack('<Q', 5707435436569584202))`.

Comment: Nah, I think I made my point about the byte values by now. :-P

Comment: @MarkRansom: I am 99.9% certain the OP wanted a byte string, 8 bytes, not it's representation as a python literal (32 bytes).

Comment: Why did you choose an unsigned type? As to using the bytes: `cast(create_string_buffer('J\xe24OJ\xe24O'), POINTER(c_uint64))[0] == 5707435436569584202` ... c'est bon.

Comment: @eryksun: As an example. Signed would be fine too, but the example given was a large positive number, so unsigned felt more applicable here.

Comment: OK, just to be complete, format 'q' will handle numbers in the inclusive range `[-2**63, 2**63 - 1]`, which will work with these examples, if supporting negative numbers is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread, but it is still useful. Here my two cents using python3:

```
hex_string = hex(5707435436569584202) # '0x4f34e24a4f34e180' as you said
bytearray.fromhex(hex_string[2:]).reverse()
```

So, the key is convert it to a bytearray and reverse it.
In one line:

```
bytearray.fromhex(hex(5707435436569584202)[2:])[::-1] # bytearray(b'J\xe24OJ\xe24O')
```

PS: You can treat "bytearray" data like "bytes" and even mix them with `b'raw bytes'`

**Update:**
As [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765294/will) points in coments, you can also manage negative integers:

> To make this work with negative integers you need to mask your input with your preferred int type output length. For example, -16 as a little endian uint32_t would be bytearray.fromhex(hex(-16 & (2**32-1))[2:])[::-1], which evaluates to bytearray(b'\xf0\xff\xff\xff')

Comment: To make this work with negative integers you need to mask your input with your preferred int type output length. For example, -16 as a little endian uint32_t would be `bytearray.fromhex(hex(-16 & (2**32-1))[2:])[::-1]`, which evaluates to `bytearray(b'\xf0\xff\xff\xff')`.